# Parameter must be an array or an object that implements Countable HTML2PDF php

Tags: php, parameters, count, html2pdf

I need to help how to fix this:  Parameter must be an array or an object that implements Countable on row 5. Could anybody help?

```
self::$_list = array();
$handle = fopen($file, 'r');
while (!feof($handle)) {
    $line = fgetcsv($handle);
    if (count($line)!=2) continue;
    self::$_list[trim($line[0])] = trim($line[1]);
}
fclose($handle);
```

Comment: Sounds like `fgetcsv` did not return an array, so that `count($line)` in the next line complains …

Comment: You haven't just upgraded to PHP 7.2 by any chance? `count` starting raising warnings in that version, you'll need to add some error handling.

Answer (score 2):

this is the correct syntax:

```
    while (!feof($handle)) {
        //$line = fgetcsv($handle);
        //if (count($line)!=2) continue;
        $line = fgetcsv($handle);
        if (null != $line && count($line)!=2) { continue; }
        self::$_list[trim($line[0])] = trim($line[1]);
    }
    fclose($handle);
```